# How to send a postman Get-Request with params as response-array of another request

Tags: arrays, parameters, request, postman, response

I'm trying to send 2 Get-Requests with Postman in which the response 1 was used for request 2, as follows:

- Request_1: GET: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
- Response_1: is a JSON with multi-data of:

```
    {   "userId": 1,
        "id": 6,
        "title": "dolorem eum magni eos aperiam quia",
        "body": "ut aspernatur ... "
    },
    {
     ...
```

There are many of them. So i have many `userId` from 1 to 10.

Now i want to take all `userId` of `Response_1` and put it in to `Request_2` by using Params in Postman:

- Request_2: GET: [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId={{testID}}](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=%7B%7BtestID%7D%7D)

[image]

How can i take all `userId` of `Response_1` in to the `Request_2` with pair `Key : Value` like that. Many thanks.

Comment: What's the issue with what you are doing right now ?

Comment: There is no bug. But response is empty

Comment: what you want to do what is the expectation , please add more details

Comment: wehre do you want to add that key value , what is the role of testID?

Comment: Expectation is: Request_2 is sent with `postId` which are from Response_1.

Comment: So postid is the key and userid is the value ? And you have to send same request multiple times with each of userid ?

Comment: {{testID}} is a global variable of this Collection. I habe defined it, and i know that i have to use it somehow, but I still can't make it ...

Comment: So postid is the key and userid is the value ? And you have to send same request multiple times with each of userid ?  ==> Exactly !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in first request test section add:**

```
 pm.environment.set("useridArray",pm.response.json().map((a)=>a.userId))
```

here we are getting userid from each object using map function , the map function returns an array.

**now in second request prerequest use:**

```
let testIDArray = pm.environment.get("useridArray")
pm.environment.set("testID",testIDArray.pop())
pm.environment.set("useridArray",testIDArray)
testIDArray.length ? postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName) : postman.setNextRequest(null)
```

Comment: @ PDHide: It works very good. I'm new in Postman. And It tooks me 4 hours !!! I have to research your code rightnow :) . Thank you very much. You make my day.

Comment: pm.info.requestName gives the name of "itself" so we are saying to run this again if the testIDarray is not empty meaning it havenot finished iterating through the userIDs